# Basic game code structure tips

Tags: javascript, game, canvas

I'm learning JavaScript and came up with this basic game code structure (using the CreateJS framework):

```
var stage;
var totalLoaded = 0;
var manifest;


var game = game || {};
game.init = {

    load: function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
        images = createjs.images || {};
        stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

        manifest = [{
            src: "http://i47.tinypic.com/swtj03.png",
            id: "circleImg"
        }, ]

        loader = new createjs.PreloadJS(false);
        loader.onFileLoad = game.init.handleFileLoad;
        loader.loadManifest(manifest);

        game.init.ticker();
        game.init.processText();
        game.init.interaction();
    },

    handleFileLoad: function (o) {
        if (o.type == "image") {
            images[o.id] = o.result = new createjs.Bitmap(o.result);
            switch (o.id) {
                case "circleImg":
                    images[o.id].y = 302;
                    break;
            }
            game.init.handleLoadComplete();
        }
    },

    handleLoadComplete: function (e) {
        totalLoaded++;
        if (manifest.length == totalLoaded) {
            game.init.handleComplete();
        }
    },

    handleComplete: function () {
        game.menu();
    },

    ticker: function () {
        createjs.Ticker.addListener(window);
        createjs.Ticker.useRAF = true;
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
    },

    text: [{
        "name": "startText",
            "content": "START",
            "style": "bold 50px Arial",
            "color": "red",
            "x": "325",
            "y": "140",
            "scaleX":"1",
            "scaleY":"1"
    },

    {
        "name": "animationComplete",
            "content": "ANIMATION COMPLETE",
            "style": "bold 50px Arial",
            "color": "red",
            "x": "125",
            "y": "140",
            "scaleX":"1",
            "scaleY":"1"
    },

    {
        "name": "animationRestart",
            "content": "RESTART TO MENU?",
            "style": "bold 20px Arial",
            "color": "gray",
            "x": "125",
            "y": "340",
            "scaleX":"1",
            "scaleY":"1"
    }

    ],


    textId: [],

    processText: function () {
        for (i = 0; i < this.text.length; i++) {
            this.textId[i] = new createjs.Text(this.text[i].content, this.text[i].style, this.text[i].color);
            this.textId[i].x = this.text[i].x;
            this.textId[i].y = this.text[i].y;
            this.textId[i].scaleX = this.text[i].scaleX;
            this.textId[i].scaleY = this.text[i].scaleY;
            this.textId[i].name = this.text[i].name;
        }
    },

    resource: function (e) {
        stage.addChild(e);
    },

    remove: function (e) {
        stage.removeChild(e);
    },

    interaction: function () {
        this.textId[0].onClick = handleClick;
        this.textId[2].onClick = handleClick;
        function handleClick(event) {
            switch (event.target.name) {
                case "startText":
                    game.init.remove(game.init.textId[0]);
                    game.init.resource(images['circleImg']);
                    game.animation.circle();
                    break;
                case "animationRestart":
                    game.restart();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

game.animation = {
    circle: function () {
        var circleTween = new createjs.Tween.get(images['circleImg'], {
            loop: false
        }).to({
            x: 800
        }, 2000, createjs.Ease.quadIn).call(function () {
            game.animation.callComplete();
        });
    },
    callComplete: function() {
        game.init.resource(game.init.textId[1]);
        game.animation.restartText();
    },
    restartText: function() {
        game.init.resource(game.init.textId[2]);

        var restartBlink = new createjs.Tween.get(game.init.textId[2], {
            loop:true
        }).to({
            scaleX: 1,
            scaleY: 1
        }, 500, createjs.Ease.quadOut)
        .to({
            scaleX: 1.1,
            scaleY: 1.1
        }, 500, createjs.Ease.quadOut)
        .to({
            scaleX: 1,
            scaleY: 1
        }, 500, createjs.Ease.quadOut)
    }

}
game.resetPositions = function() {
    images['circleImg'].x = 0;
}
game.restart = function () {
    stage.removeAllChildren();
    game.resetPositions();
    game.menu();
}
game.menu = function () {
    game.init.resource(game.init.textId[0]);
}


tick = function () {
    stage.update();
}​
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8kXc/2/)

([old version before changes](http://jsfiddle.net/f8kXc/))

Is this a viable basic game structure? How can I improve game data storage (in this basic case text storage) and naming?

EDIT: added repeat functionality and a dedicated namespace.

Answer (score 3):

From a once over:

- Object notation does not require the properties to be quoted, you can simply do this:

  ```
  {
    name: "startText",
    content: "START",
    style: "bold 50px Arial",
    color: "red",
    x: 325,
    y: 140,
    scaleX:1,
    scaleY:1
  }
  ```

  Note that I also removed quotes from the numeric constants, you do not need them.
- I would have named your text array `texts` instead of `text`
- There are some variables you are not declaring with `var` : `i`, `images`, and `loader`, this pollutes the global namespace.
- It is better to use `images.circleImg` then `images['circleImg']`.
- There is no need capture the results of `new createjs.Tween` into `circleTween` and `restartBlink` since you do nothing with those variables
- The magic number `500`, `2000` and `800` in `restartText` should be capture in a single constant
- This : `this.textId[0].onClick = handleClick;` is old skool, please look into [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)
- I would have made `stage`, `totalLoaded` and `manifest` part of `game`
- I would add some error handling to `loader` especially if you are loading an image from a different domain..
- On  a final note, the jsfiddle does not work for me, but then again, this a 2012 question ;)